# Port opened with ufw shown closed by nmap

Tags: 18.04, firewall, ufw, smtp

I need to open port 465 on my PC. I ran the following succesfully.

```
root@user:/home/user# ufw allow 465
Rule added
Rule added (v6)
```

But when I scan with nmap. I get-

```
root@user:/home/user# nmap -p465 localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-03 20:21 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00013s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
465/tcp closed smtps

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.34 seconds
```

What should I do?

Note:I have tried iptables.But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is there anything actually listening on that interface + port? check with netstat and/or lsof

Comment: thats because there is no running process on that port. use ```netstat -a``` to show open ports with running processes.